# OpenAL TCP Audio Streaming C++ WINDOWS

Tags: c++, windows, audio, stream, openal

I am trying to make a program which works like phonecall. I included OpenAL libarary. I successfully hear the voice which I recorded like echo. But I want to record voice 50 ms and send it via socket every 50 ms.
And the other guy should receive the buff daha from socket and play it.

```
    int main()
{
    ALCdevice *dev[2];
    ALCcontext *ctx;
    ALuint source, buffers[3];
    char data[5000];
    ALuint buf;
    ALint val;

    float ttotal;
    unsigned int ccount;
    long int c1ount;
    c1ount = 0;

    dev[0] = alcOpenDevice(NULL);
    ctx = alcCreateContext(dev[0], NULL);
    alcMakeContextCurrent(ctx);

    alGenSources(1, &source);
    alGenBuffers(3, buffers);

    /* Setup some initial silent data to play out of the source */
    alBufferData(buffers[0], AL_FORMAT_MONO16, data, sizeof(data), 22050);
    alBufferData(buffers[1], AL_FORMAT_MONO16, data, sizeof(data), 22050);
    alBufferData(buffers[2], AL_FORMAT_MONO16, data, sizeof(data), 22050);
    alSourceQueueBuffers(source, 3, buffers);

    /* If you don't need 3D spatialization, this should help processing time */
    alDistanceModel(AL_NONE);

    dev[1] = alcCaptureOpenDevice(NULL, 22050, AL_FORMAT_MONO16, sizeof(data) / 2); //22050 mean 22.050 samples per     second. or 44100 for 44.1 per second.

                                                                                    /* Start playback and capture, and enter the audio loop */
    alSourcePlay(source);
    alcCaptureStart(dev[1]);    //starts ring buffer

    while (1)
    {
        /* Check if any queued buffers are finished */
        alGetSourcei(source, AL_BUFFERS_PROCESSED, &val);
        if (val <= 0)
            continue;

        /* Check how much audio data has been captured (note that 'val' is the
        * number of frames, not bytes) */
        alcGetIntegerv(dev[1], ALC_CAPTURE_SAMPLES, 1, &val);

        /* Read the captured audio */
        alcCaptureSamples(dev[1], data, val);


        //***** Process/filter captured data here *****//


        c1ount = c1ount + 1;
        if (c1ount >= 33) {
            break;
        }


        //for (int ii=0;ii<val;++ii) {
        //  data[ii]*=0.1; // Make it quieter
        //}
        //***** end Process/filter captured data here *****//

        /* Pop the oldest finished buffer, fill it with the new capture data,
        then re-queue it to play on the source */
        alSourceUnqueueBuffers(source, 1, &buf);
        alBufferData(buf, AL_FORMAT_MONO16, data, val * 2 /* bytes here, not
                                                          frames */, 22050);
        alSourceQueueBuffers(source, 1, &buf);

        /* Make sure the source is still playing */
        alGetSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &val);

        if (val != AL_PLAYING)
        {

            alSourcePlay(source);
        }
    }

    cout << "fgggggggg\n";


    /* Shutdown and cleanup */
    alcCaptureStop(dev[1]);
    alcCaptureCloseDevice(dev[1]);

    alSourceStop(source);
    alDeleteSources(1, &source);
    alDeleteBuffers(3, buffers);
    alDeleteBuffers(1, &buf);

    alcMakeContextCurrent(NULL);
    alcDestroyContext(ctx);
    alcCloseDevice(dev[0]);

    return 0;


}
```

I dont know how to play audio from buffs received from socket. I tried

```
        alSourceQueueBuffers(source, 1, &buf);

    /* Make sure the source is still playing */
    alGetSourcei(source, AL_SOURCE_STATE, &val);

    if (val != AL_PLAYING)
    {

        alSourcePlay(source);
    }
```

but it doesnt work. *I dont hear anything*
Thanks

Comment: "_but it doesnt work._" is an useless problem description. Please elaborate on how, **exactly**, it doesn't work.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I dont hear anything

Comment: I forgot to mention: Please [edit] the question with relevant information instead of adding it in the comments.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius So you dont know how to fix it? I did not say I got an error I said it doesnt work that means I dont hear anything. Why are you taking care about this. Everybody understand no data playing when they read It doesnt work.

Comment: 1) "_I did not say I got an error I said it doesnt work_" I have seen plenty of people, that were describing their problems as "_it doesn't work_", when the actual problem was ranging from compilation error, to Segmentation Fault, to incorrect output, and that is exactly the problem of such a statement. It doesn't mean **anything**. We are not _you_, hence we can't infer what "_doesn't work_" means to _you_. If you don't hear anything - why can't you just say that? It conveys more meaning, than "_doesn't work_". 2) If I knew the answer - I would answer. I merely asked for clarification.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius If you dont have enough knowladge to fix the problem click back to find elementer level problems. Dont waste my time. Thanks for your warnings.